# The image is not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

pretty new to HTML and CSS here. I've just built one page and working on a second one with bootstrap. It seems like everything is working fine except for the picture I have chosen for the site. It will not fit inside of its div when I use "img-fluid" and am not sure what else to try while still keeping it bootstrap compliant. Using "img-fluid" makes it look strange on Ipad and other bigger mobile types. Also, is writing my own media queries a normal part of using bootstrap? I wasn't sure if I should refrain from writing them at all with bootstrap?

Ipad:
[image]
Mobile:

[image]

Comment: Your have forgotten to attach html/css code. We can't debug images.

Comment: It's because your photo width is smaller than its parent and the image stretches if you add ``img-fluid`` class to the img. You must increase the width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

use this in a css file or a style tag in the head:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    //mobile css here
}
```

you should know that Bootstrap isn't a CSS alternative. Bootstrap only to help you write less CSS.